# Do any Android devices have square screens?

Tags: android, screen, screen-resolution

I'm writing a game for Android and am laying out the playing screen myself, handling both vertical and horizontal orientations, and haven't done anything if the width and height are the same.

Does anybody know of at least one Android device that has a perfectly square screen resolution?

Comment: Does it really matter if one exists today? It could happen in the future, so maybe it would make sense to handle the scenario.

Comment: You don't need to do anything when the width and height are the same, as Android simply reuses all the resources from the current orientation when you rotate a square screen. You can verify that by creating a virtual device with a screen aspect ratio of 1:1 and test your app on it. Press Ctrl+F11 to rotate the screen in the emulator and see that the activity is not destroyed and so it's not re-created, but whatever the current layout is, it's being re-used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [WIMM ONE](http://www.wimm.com/platform-technology.html) is the only square screen Android device out there. It has capacitive touch display at 160x160.

Comment: That's extremely low resolution.  What would one do with so few pixels?

Comment: @Kibbee It's a really cool device--one would display data, icons, etc. It doesn't take many pixels to run a watch-size device and be useful.

Comment: It's not, but it's one of the few readily-available ones. Why dupe an existing answer?

Comment: what resources will android choose for such a device ? res/layout-land or res/layout-port ? will it even switch between them when rotating the device?

Comment: @[android developer] It will not switch between resources when rotating a square screen.

Answer (score 3):

The [MotoACTV](https://motoactv.com/) is 220x176 (not square but close), the [WIMM One](http://www.wimm.com/) is 160x160 (square).

The MotoACTV has been rooted, but the default device runs a customized Android. It's a pretty cool device, though. The WIMM is slick and runs a more-standard Android.

Answer (score 1):

None the I'm aware of.  Every device I'm familiar with has a distinctive "portrait" vs "landscape" mode.

It would probably be wise to make sure your code can always gracefully handle portrait vs landscape - even if you ever happen to run across a square device.

Conversely, if you *want* a square - just "crop" the image appropriately.  The cropping, of course, will become "zero" if you ever encounter this hypothetical "square screen". :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather late answer to this question, but things have changed somewhat since then, and although there are still no mainstream Android devices with square screens, there are 3 square BlackBerry devices (Q10, Q5, and Passport) that can run Android apps, and so would fall under that criteria. Interestingly, when an app is run on a square BlackBerry Passport, and the device is rotated to its side, the app also rotates, however none of the `onPause()`, `onStop()`, or `onDestroy()` events are called, and so the activity is not destroyed and re-created, but the current activity layout is re-used. So, in that respect, nothing happens, and you don't have to worry about saving/loading resources and such.

This behaviour is actually built-in in Android -- it will only destroy and re-create an activity, if the screen dimensions change. The API docs don't talk about this edge case, as there are no square Android devices, but you can see that the reason for destroying and re-creating the activity during orientation change is to load alternative resources specific for the new orientation. Since rotating a square device doesn't change the screen dimensions, there is no need to load alternative resources, and therefore, there's no need to destory and re-create an activity. I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the [Motorola Flipout](http://www.motorola.com/Support/GB-EN/Consumer-Support/Mobile-Phones/MOTOROLA_FLIPOUT_with_MOTOBLUR) is one.

Comment: Motorola Flipout has 320x240px screen

Comment: Indeed.  Its still square shaped.. :)

Comment: Although the OP specifically mentions width and height being the same. Dunno if it was worth someone's down vote or not, but I'm mildly sympathetic.

Comment: Sometimes we just go by the headlines.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov That is still counted as a square screen for anyone in this space as its a UI concern.