# Is there a list of largest and smallest real Android device screens in existence per Android version?

Tags: android

I have an app that targets Android 4.1+. My designer is working on a screen that has a lot of information and we are trying to make sure it will fit on the smallest possible screen size given my minimum Android version. Is there such a list for actual real existing devices?

Thank you.

Comment: Screen size isn't related to Android OS version. Read: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html You should have some idea of your target user and the devices are willing to support. Note that not all devices are rectangles, [Do any Android devices have square screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260532/295004) And given that there are  thousands of Android devices, any 'list' would be outdated soon after publication.

Comment: I guess you are right, I was just hoping someone could at least say for a phone that shipped with 4.1 with a very small screen and density combination these are the dimensions so we aren't designing for a space that might be smaller than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android as an operating system does not define a screen size minimum. However, if you really want a number to reference your best bet may be to consult the compatibility definition document. Google requires that vendors adhere to these requirements if they wish to include Google's proprietary apps in their devices (such as the play store). Almost all commercially available mainstream android phones fit into this category.

You can view the CDDs all listed here:

https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd

And you can see here for android 4.1 screen sizes

https://source.android.com/compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd - scroll to section 7.1.1

which states "Devices MUST have screen sizes of at least 426 dp x 320 dp ('small')" along with a few more rules

Answer (score 0):

There is no master list as per API and screen size but here are few alternatives, I Don't know if you have gone through these links or not but here are few of them you might find helpful.

[Device Metrics](https://material.io/devices/)

[PDF list of supported devices by play store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)

[Wiki link for android devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Android_(operating_system)_devices)

[List of Jelly Bean devices](http://www.coolpctips.com/2012/07/android-jelly-bean-devices-list-of-smartphones/)